# Select all vector features underneath the mouse cursor (clientside)

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a number of polygons that are exactly equal **covering each other** and shown on one layer. When using OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature - only the topmost feature is selected.

How to get info on other features, which are under the topmost polygon?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was done like this:
Event on click, get the coordinates of the click, get features on current extent, and finally select features intersecting dot with the coordinates (initially clicked on).

повесил событие на тычок на карте - нашел координаты тычка - нашел список полигонов на карте - выбрал те которые пересекаются с точкой - выделил их
по скорости приемлимо